# android US Locale not working

Tags: android, locale

I have the following problem:

I want to change the language of my app programmatically.

So I used shared Preferences to change the locale.

```
        Locale locale2 = new Locale("b0"); 
        Locale.setDefault(locale2);
        Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
        config2.locale = locale2;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

b0 is the saved local.

b0 is working flawlessly with the German locale de and the English locale en , but not with the US one: en_US

Ofcourse I added a new folder:

```
res/values-en-rUS
```

With the american strings xml.

If I change the Language of my Phone to English (United States), the App starts with American English.

I even edited my lines to:

```
            Locale locale2 = new Locale("en_US");
```

Still not working.

Is Anything wrong with "en_US"?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Any Help is very much accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I just found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21860061/1287856) (see [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)).

In your case, you should write:

```
Locale locale2 = new Locale("en","US");
```

The general function, in scala-based language, would be the following:

```
val locale = if(name contains '_') {
  val splitted = sign.split("_")
  new Locale(splitted(0),splitted(1))
} else {
  new Locale(name); 
}
```

Else it defines a new language code `en_us` which is not what you want.