# Java Locale case sensitivity

Tags: java, localization

I have the following code to display current locale

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println(new Locale("en_US"));
```

The above gives output as follows

```
en_US
en_us
```

How do I construct a Locale instance which gives `en_US` ?

**EDIT**

I am asking this because my resources which is `Messages_en_US.properties` is being ignored when I try to set it as default locale if any exception occurs during

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages", new Locale("en_US"));
```

Comment: Do you want a _new_ `en_US` `Locale` object or Java's `en_US` `Locale`?

Comment: See my edited question, I hope it clarifies it.

Comment: Did you try Locale.US ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
new Locale("en_US")
```

is a Locale whose language code is `"en_us"`.

```
new Locale("en", "US")
```

is a locale whose language code is `"en"`, and whose country code is `"US"`.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String%29) says of the single-argument constructor:

> ## Locale
>
> ```
> public Locale(String language)
> ```
>
> Construct a locale from a language code. This constructor normalizes the language value to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

[docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html)

```
System.out.println(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"));
```

Comment: Caveat: `forLanguageTag` is only available in JDK7.